# Convergence of heat flow on non-compact manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, heat-equation

Consider the heat equation $\partial_t u= \Delta u+\lambda_1 u$ on a non-compact complete manifold $M$ (with nonpositive curvature) where $\lambda_1$ is the first eigenvalue and we start with some smooth initial data $u_0$ at $t=0.$ Then does the heat flow converge to the first eigenfunction on $M$?

Comment: eigenfunction/eigenvalue in what sense? $L^2$?

Comment: yeah, that's right

Comment: Convergence in which sense? $L^2$-convergence follows from the spectral theorem. Do you want something stronger?

Comment: @MaoWao I'd love to see a proof of that in an answer, is  the convergence  rate exponential? Does one also have convergence   $C^0$  on compact subsets?

Comment: @Overflowian See my answer. Regarding exponential decay, an estimate of the form $\lVert u_t-u_\infty\rVert_2\leq e^{-\alpha t}\lVert u_0-u_\infty\rVert_2$ is equivalent to a gap of size at least $\alpha$ between $\lambda_1$ and the rest of the spectrum.

Comment: To see that the convergence cannot possibly be exponential in general, note that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a non-compact complete manifold with nonpositive curvature and the bottom of the spectrum is 0. Exact decay rate of the heat equation on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is well known (using the fundamental solution).

Comment: I should also mention that certainly starting with "some smooth initial data" is not enough. You have to have some decay assumption at infinity for the data. On $\mathbb{R}^n$, for example, there exists smooth, non-converging solutions to the heat equation. [I wrote about them on my blog](https://qnlw.info/post/oscillatory-heat-201910/). (With a little bit of work you can make the initial data smooth; the data shown is already uniformly bounded, so it is not based on any trickery related to the non-uniqueness problem.)

Comment: Thank you for the discussions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following answer only applies if $u_0\in L^2$, and it mostly relies on abstract operator theoretic arguments. I am sure more could be said by exploiting the geometric structure.

The Laplace-Beltrami operator on a complete manifold is essentially self-adjoint on $C_c^\infty$. Since $\lambda_1$ is the bottom of the spectrum of $-\Delta$, the operator $-(\Delta+\lambda_1)$ has a unique positive self-adjoint extension, which I denote by $A$. The heat flow is given by $e^{-tA}u_0$.

Let $E$ denote the spectral measure of $A$ and $d\mu(\lambda)=d\langle u_0,E(\lambda) u_0\rangle$. Note that $\mu$ is a finite measure on $\mathbb R_+$ with $\mu(\mathbb R_+)=\lVert u_0\rVert_2^2$. By the spectral theorem we have
$$
\lVert A^k(e^{-tA}-1_{\{0\}}(A))u_0\rVert_2^2=\int_{[0,\infty)}\lambda^{2k}(e^{-t\lambda}-1_{\{0\}}(\lambda))^2\,d\mu(\lambda).
$$
For $t\geq t_0$ (and $\lambda\geq 0$) we have
$$
\lambda^{2k}(e^{-t\lambda}-1_{\{0\}}(\lambda))^2\leq \lambda^{2k}e^{-2t\lambda}\lesssim_k t_0^{-2k}.
$$
Thus $\lVert A^k(e^{-tA}-1_{\{0\}}(A))u_0\rVert_2^2\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ by the dominated convergence theorem.

The operator $1_{\{0\}}(A)$ is the projection onto $\ker(\Delta+\lambda_1)$. In particular, if $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of $-\Delta$, then $1_{\{0\}}(A)u_0$ is an eigenfunction of $-\Delta$. In the following I will write $u_t$ for $e^{-tA}u_0$ and $u_\infty$ for $1_{\{0\}}(A)u_0$. By what we have seen before, $u_t\to u_\infty$ in $L^2$.

By elliptic regularity and Sobolev embedding, if $m\in\mathbb N$ and $2k\geq m+\dim(M)/2+1$, then
$$
\lVert u_t-u_\infty\rVert_{C^m(\Omega)}\lesssim_{m,\Omega}\lVert u_t-u_\infty\rVert_{H^{2k}(\Omega)}\lesssim_{k,\Omega}\lVert A^k(u_t-u_\infty)\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}+\lVert u_t-u_\infty\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$
for every sufficiently nice bounded domain $\Omega$ in $M$.

Therefore, $u_t\to u_\infty$ in $C^m$ on compact subsets for every $m\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by signs here, you seems to say that the spectrum of $-\Delta $ satisfies $\sigma(-\Delta)\subset (\lambda_1,+\infty)$.

So is the definition of $\lambda_1 $ given by $\inf \sigma(-\Delta)$?.
I thought that it was the smallest positive eigenvalue and in particular it should be *contained* in the spectrum.

Comment: I took $\lambda_1$ to mean the bottom of the spectrum of $-\Delta$ (which is actually contained in the spectrum because it is closed). Of course, if $\lambda_1$ is embedded in the spectrum, this is no longer true -- then you can have approximate eigenfunctions of the bottom of the spectrum for which $e^{t(\Delta+\lambda_1)}u_0$ blows up in $L^2$ norm.

Comment: So $-\Delta-\lambda_1$ is positive *semi*-definite, does it still have a unique extension?

Comment: Yes, essential self-adjointness is stable under additive bounded (self-adjoint) perturbations.

Comment: By the way, you didn't use the extra hypothesis of non-positive curvature, didn't you?

Comment: For your question that is completely unimportant. The proof that @MaoWao provided works equally well on compact manifolds, possibly with positive curvature. But on compacts since the spectrum is discrete you will have spectral gap and the convergence is exponential.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this has been very helpful!